# User verification on ASP.NET and MySQL fails on live

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I'm not a developer, but need to fix an app that is based on .NET (2.0) and MySQL. I have searched quite a bit, hence the question.

Checked everything on staging, and it seems to be working fine. However, when move to live, users cannot log in. Exact same setup, just change the connection string and connects to the staging database and user log in. I also know that in both circumstances a connection to the database is being made. Users can register and are added to the database.

I believe the same happens when the .NET applications connect to a SQL Server database, however, it is possible to change "applicationname" in the web.config.

So the questions are:

1. Is there also an "applicationname" change for MySQL?
2. Could there be anything else causing the problems?

Comment: Did you check for errors in the server's event viewer?

Comment: Is the connection string using integrated security?  If so you need to verify access to the database for all accounts running in your production setup.  Also if you could provide error messages that you are receiving then I am sure someone could answer it here much faster.

Comment: Hi again. Thanks everyone. This is shared hosting, and I tried via IIS manager - but can't see error logs. By integrated security - did you mean integrated mode? Yes, in that case. Error message is based on the app itself which is username/password is incorrect. Another thing that I noticed, is when I click on submit - the status bar at the bottom of the browser says "Waiting for..." and the user logs in . However, when connected to live, the status bar does not change. Does that help a bit more?